# Filter view based on current user's role and taxonomy terms

Tags: views

I have three content types.

- Article
- Basic Page
- Custom Page

All the content types have a *field_interests* field, which can have multiple values, and which is an entity reference field to the *interests* vocabulary.

The taxonomy terms for that vocabulary are:

- sports
- songs
- movies

I have three user roles.

- Athlete
- Singer
- Actor

I want to create a view in which:

- *Athlete* users can view nodes for which the value of *field_interests* is *sports*
- The *Singer* users can view nodes for which the value of *field_interests* is *songs*
- The Actor users can view nodes for which the value of *field_interests* is *movies*

I am assuming filter condition should be like this

```
( current user's role == athlete AND "field_interests"==sports ) OR
( current user's role == Singer AND "field_interests"==songs) OR
( current user's role == Actor AND "field_interests"==movies)
// if any user has multiple user roles 
( All current user roles in [Singer , Actor] AND All "field_interests" in [songs , movies] )
```

I saw similar questions and I don't know how to use those answers to my exact purpose.

Comment: Roles in Drupal are not exclusive (each user can have multiple roles).  So what should happen if a user has the roles of Actor and Singer?

Comment: This will be much easier if you create 3 separate views, each view showing only one "interest". And then limit access to those views by assigning the corresponding permissions to your user roles.

Comment: @Hudri Yeah, I tried that but, If I have to create 15 views which should display content based on role and suppose I have 10 roles , In that case I have to create 150 views . Which is , I feel not a good practice.

Comment: @PatrickKenny In my case I'll make sure every user has a single role. but, In any case if user has roles of Actor and Singer, I want to add new condition like ```all current user roles in [Actor , Singer]```

Comment: @PatrickKenny how can I set taxonomy term value dynamically [seeHere](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/308415/how-to-add-filters-in-drupal-8-dynamically), need help