# How do I dynamically add filters?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms, blocks

I have a view_block with the following filters,

[image]

I want to change the product tag, Release tag, Document type values dynamically based on url.

if the url is, `example.com/mars/21.43.00/ProductGuide`, then the filters should change like this

[image]

I don't know how to achieve this, any suggestion would be helpful

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to use a contextual filter for that

Comment: yes, I thought of that but it's not working in my case. could you explain me your way of approaching this? product tag, release tag, document type are taxonomy terms. can we apply contextual filters to these three?